# No Module Error while importing lru_cache

Tags: python, json, jsonschema, lru

Python Version : 2.6

I have installed `jsonschema` module.

While trying to run schema validation, I am getting `ImportError: No module named lru`. The function I am using is this :

```
def validateConfig(jsonContent):
    try:
        jsonschema.validate(jsonContent, json.loads(schema))
    except jsonschema.ValidationError as e:
        print e.message
    except jsonschema.SchemaError as e:
        print e.message
```

Errors I get :

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jsonschema-2.5.1-py2.6.egg/jsonschema/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from jsonschema.exceptions import (
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jsonschema-2.5.1-py2.6.egg/jsonschema/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
from jsonschema import _utils
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jsonschema-2.5.1-py2.6.egg/jsonschema/_utils.py", line 6, in <module>
from jsonschema.compat import str_types, MutableMapping, urlsplit
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/jsonschema-2.5.1-py2.6.egg/jsonschema/compat.py", line 37, in <module>
from repoze.lru import lru_cache
ImportError: No module named lru
```

Other things I have tried :

- Get the latest compatible `repoze.lru module` from `pypi`
- Also tried running these in `python terminal`

  - `from repoze.lru import lru_cache`
  - `from repoze.lru import lru`
  - `from repoze.lru import *`

All of the above gives the same error :

```
>> import repoze
>> from repoze.lru import lru_cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named repoze.lru
```

Comment: There are a lot of typos in your answer. Maybe this is the cause of the issue? repoze <---> repoz

Comment: Yeah I would suspect pip reinstalling jsonschema or even whatever library *repoze* is a part of will sort this

Comment: my bad on the typing ... its "repoze" everywhere